# How to keep a fixed element away a specific distance from the document bottom?

Tags: jquery, css, position, fixed

I have an element with position:fixed, bottom:0px.
As I scroll down the page this element is supposed to follow me until it gets closer to the footer, lets say 100px height, I am trying to allow the element stay at bottom:0px until it reaches the footer element, in that moment it should always let the footer element be below it.

This is my css:

```
#backToTop{
    width:80px;
    height:50px;
    background:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:550px;
}
```

I have looked into Jquery's `$(document).height()` and `$(window).scrollTop()` to try to come up with some kind of conditional that will detect when the position of the element is close to the footer, but no success (the height of my footer is 120):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){    
if($(document).height()-($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()) <= 120){
    $('#backToTop').css({'bottom':$(document).height()-($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height())});
}else{
    $('#backToTop').css('bottom',0);
}
});
```

I am not quite sure where exactly those values are pointing to, any hints? Thanks.

Comment: can you do a jsfiddle example with your html and all

Comment: Please write your example in jsfiddle or write your html code in question...!

Comment: Here, thanks: http://jsfiddle.net/6bZab/, I got it to work, now the problem is that the element misteriously moves to the right as it reaches the footer.

Comment: Sorry guys, wrong link, this is the good one:http://jsfiddle.net/mscxp/AFDkC/ the first time you open it and scroll it moves to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating two classes for the #backToTop element, one for fixed and another for relative position. When footer reaches the viewport, #backToTop element changes its class to 'relative'.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="backToTop" class="fixed_pos">Top</div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
float: left;
}

#backToTop {
width:80px;
height:50px;
background:#333;
color:#FFF;
text-align:center;
border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
padding-top:10px;    
left: 50%;
margin-left: -40px;
}

.fixed_pos {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;    
}

.relative_pos {
position: relative;
top: 100%;
}

footer {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 100%;
background: #333;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}
```

Have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6bZab/

Comment: Excellent that is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot @kapantzak. The only problem in your example is that if we scroll down slowly the element back to top jumps as it meets with the footer. I found a way to do it by getting changing the bottom value as the element reaches the footer, I will post the answer here. Thanks a lot, you really helped!

Comment: Here is the code @kapantzak: http://jsfiddle.net/6bZab/, Now something really weird happens, as soon as the element reaches the footer it moves a few pixels to the right!!!

Comment: I see that the code works correctly.. the element doen't move to the right! Are you sure for that?

Comment: LOL! I just realized I never showed you my code. I made a link to yours. here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/mscxp/AFDkC/ the first time you open it and scroll it moves to the right

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `position:sticky` property to achieve a similar result.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4hznD/

Here's the CSS code, the `<div>` you want to place in fixed must be placed in the page flow at 100px from the bottom:

## CSS

```
div{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: gray;
}
```

I don't know the actual `position:sticky` support (I know for sure it works on Chrome) but you may think using some polyfills when missing.

Comment: Hey this is 2016 calling.
position:sticky still isn't widely supported. 

It was even dropped in Chrome 37 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

Also, except for "-webkit-", those vendor prefixes don't exist.